# ¿Cómo restringir un rating bar en android studio para que el usuario con cuenta vote solo una vez?

Tags: android, base-de-datos, firebase

Este es mi `ratingBar`: cada que el mismo usuario presiona varias veces la estrella me está contabilizando varios votos, y solo debería contabilizar uno solo voto.

```
 ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
            calificar(ratingBar.getRating());
            //crearVoto();
            //contarVotos();

        }
    });
```

mi método que va contando los votos:

```
 public void contarVotos(double rating) {

    //asignar dato a un campo de la bd:
    //databaseReference.child("Profesor").child(id).child("calificacion").setValue(rating);
    //para obtener un dato de un campo de la bd:
    databaseReference.child("Profesor").child(id).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                int votoUsuario = 0;
                Profesor objeto = dataSnapshot.getValue(Profesor.class);
                votoUsuario = objeto.getVotacion();
                int sumaVotos = votoUsuario + 1;
                databaseReference.child("Profesor").child(id).child("votacion").setValue(sumaVotos);
            } else {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Observación: ya usé el método `ratingBar.setEnabled(false)`, y eso solamente hace que se desactive, pero si el usuario vuelve a entrar a esa ventada puede seguir calificando.

Answer (score 0):

Vas a tener un problema de concurrencia cuando 2 o mas usuarios esten votando al mismo tiempo y el resultado de la votacion va a depender de uno o de otro y entonces la cantidad de votos no se va a ver adecuadamente, lo que te sugiero es usar transacciones para hacer estas escrituras.

Si no quieres que el usuario vuelva a votar , cada vez que abre la seccion para votar deberias chequear si ese usuario ya voto, para eso deberias hacer una consulta a Firebase que te traiga si el usuario que esta conectado ya voto , para eso podes almacenar el user id del usuario que voto en una tabla en la cual el valor de la tabla sea el uid y la key el id del elemento donde contas votos, entonces pasas por ese nodo y te fijas si no existe ese user id, si existe es por que ya voto y podes obtener el post que voto, de esa forma no le pedis mas para votar

Otra opcion menos eficiente es usar sharedpreferences, una vez que vota luego de `calificar(ratingBar.getRating());`  guardas en sharedpreferences un valor booleano que diga que ya voto y la proxima vez que tengas que mostrar el ratingbar no lo muestras si ese usuario ya voto

Comment: Gracias, lo que hice fue que apenas diera clic el usuario en alguna de las estrellas se guardara ese voto en firebase con el nombre de user, e hice una validación para que cada que entrara a esa ventana de votacion, primero verificara en bd si ya habia votado, dependiendo de eso, activaba o no el rating.En general lo mismo que dices

Comment: Genial, si te sirvio la respuesta no olvides macarla como correcta, un saludo !